# How to create Tableview hierarchy from JSON?

Tags: ios, json, swift, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller

I am trying to build a simple app but surprisingly I could not find any answers helping me.

The root view would be a UINavigationController and inside it, I would like to put a UITableViewController that I would populate with UITableViewCells from data within a dictionary. When I would click on one of the UITableViewCell, it would redirect me to another UITableViewController populated from my dictionary as well.

```
[
        "name": "Functions",
        "icon": "calculator",
        "subcategories": [
            [
                "name": "Plan Leg",
                "icon": "globe",
                "subcategories": [
                    [
                        "name": "Heading & Groundspeed",
                        "destination": ""
                    ],
                    [
                        "name": "Time & Distance",
                        "destination": ""
                    ],
                    [
                        "name": "Fuel & Distance",
                        "destination": ""
                    ],
                ]
            ]
       ]
]
```

For example here, I would love to create a TableViewController called "Functions" with one TableViewCell "Plan Leg" that redirects to another TableViewController with the 3 cells "Heading & Groundspeed", "Time & Distance", and "Fuel & Distance"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class CatagoriesArray : Decodable {
    var catagories : [Catagories]?
}
class Catagories : Decodable {
    var name : String?
    var icon : String? 
    var subcategories : [Subcategories]?
}

class Subcategories : Decodable {
    var name : String? 
    var icon : String? 
    var subcategories : [SubcategoriesType]?
 }

 class SubcategoriesType : Decodable {
    var name : String? 
    var destination : String?
 }
```

add this line for decoding

```
 let model = try? JSONDecoder().decode(CatagoriesArray.self, from: data) // data that will come from API response
```

in "Functions" tableViewController

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    self.title = model[0].name // prints "Functions"
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return model[0].subcategories.count 
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "identifier", for: indexPath) 
    cell.nameLabel.text = model[0].subcategories.name
    return cell
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let vc = self.storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier : "identifier") as! FuncCatagory
    vc.subcategories = model[0].subcategories[indexPath.row]
    self.navigationController.pushViewController(vc, animated : true)
}
```

in `FuncCatagory` populate tableview as like the same code